# How do I parse @import stylesheets with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to read CSS selectors in my stylesheets with the `document.styleSheets` array. It works fine with `<link>` and `<style>` tags, but when I use `@import` inside a `<style>` it doesn't show up in the array - only as a cssRule (style is "Undefined" in Safari 3 and FF 3).

So: How can I parse the css in an @imported file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that our document contains an @import-rule as first rule in the first stylesheet, here's the code for standards compliant browsers

```
document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].styleSheet.cssRules;
```

and the special case for our all-beloved IE

```
document.styleSheets[0].imports[0].rules;
```

You could have easily figured this out yourself if you had read [the page at quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_css.html#access) to which I had already linked and then walked the properties of the `@import`-rule with a `for..in` loop - that's what I did...

**PS:** I can't comment on other answers yet, but if I could, I would have ridiculed you properly ;)

Comment: Go ahead =) (slapping my own forehead) I thought I had checked the properties but I must have made a mistake somewhere. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Christoph: Now you can comment ;)

Comment: Note that once you have a `CSSImportRule` object you can access the [stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSImportRule/stylesheet) property and from there access the `cssRules` property like the answer shows. However, if the URL of your `@import` rule is wrong (i.e. produces a 404 response) THEN THE `cssRules` PROPERTY WILL BE EMPTY! This tripped me up until I fixed the URL used for the `@import` rule, then everything worked!

Answer (score 4):

> Check this page - which further links to this one on quirksmode.org.

Thanks, but I have tried that... the Quirksmode examples never parse stylesheets embedded with @import.

If I have this HTML/CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/test1.css" />

<style type="text/css">

    @import url('css/test2.css');

    div {
        color: blue;
    }

</style>
```

... then document.styleSheets.length is 2 (the link tag and the style tag). The CSS file that is linked through @import will be available as

```
document.styleSheets[1].cssRules[0].
```

In other words, a CSS rule. This can also be seen at the [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/changess.html) page that you mentioned, Christoph. I can get its cssText ("@import url('css/test2.css');") but I can't figure out how to parse the CSS inside the file (test2.css)...

If I have totally missed something obvious here, feel free to ridicule me... :)

Answer (score 3):

Excellent page with lots of stylesheet parsing info: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domstylesheets